# PC Stuck on verifying DMI pool - taken many steps

Tags: boot, motherboard, bios, desktop-computer, cmos

I have an old computer I am attempting to restore. It's a msi 945g series chipset board. I began with no POST beeps and no monitor signal being detected.

I have....

- Removed, Cleaned and Reseated both RAM sticks I have
- Removed my video card, cleaned and reseated
- Restored all fail-safe defaults in CMOS and BIOS
- Removed CMOS battery carefully, waited 25 mins, replaced and powered on box

Currently the box now boots and I get a single short beep during POST, however then it hangs and refuses to pass the 'Verifying DMI Pool Data....' stage. I have put in a USB drive and tried to boot from that with no luck.

I can hear the HDD is spinning just fine and its exact model number shows up in my drive priority listing within the CMOS menus. The power supply was brand new when this thing broke a month later so I know it wouldn't be this. I am wondering if the fact that I am using a USB keyboard and mouse might cause problems, but then im sure there would be a device missing message.

There are no CMOS jumpers I could locate anywhere near it so I am hoping that I didn't need to find some elsewhere. There are jumpers only near my HDD to board input, SATA I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had same issue today (Arch Linux iso)

Was fine installing on new laptop, but old system (15 yo, Athlon 64 smth cpu) hang with same premise.

Fixed by remaking the USB boot stick - downloaded latest Rufus, checked all compatibility checkboxes (MBR, "Add fixes for old Bioses", use dd write) and voila - it ran smoothly this time.

Answer (score 1):

Statistically, the most times I encountered this problem it was the PSU at fault. PSU would not provide enough power in order for the system to boot up, due to bad capacitors. If you have an onboard video card, try removing the discrete card and try again to boot with onboard-only. If it works, its certainly the PSU.

Considering what you already tested, two things are left to check: make sure there is no disk present (CD,FD,Stick) and check for connection that may be loose or even disconnected.

If none of the above is at fault, then it's a more serious hardware problem, but lets hope that is not the case.

Comment: lol now that you mention it my cd/dvd drives wont open and I am not certain if both are empty.... I have unplugged the cables from the dvd drive in question which was plugged in with the slave drive. I will now try removing the video card as well.

Comment: For the DVD drive, use a small thin pin/needle in the hole it has; there is a gear there that when pushed will mechanically open the unit.

Comment: ok when I removed the video card and switched to onboard I now finally have a "keyboard missing" message. Perhaps the USB keyboard?

Comment: hmm. except the keys still work fine and I can use the keyboard that it says is missing... hmmm

Comment: ok thanks for the tip I got both cd/dvd drives open and they were empty. Upon turning off and on my comp I no longer get the keyboard missing error. Back to just verifying DMI pool...